# I can run my Spring-boot application can't debug instead of run is throws Invalid parameter name ""

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I can run my `Spring-boot` application and hit `API`, but when I click on debug instead of run is throws Caused by:

> java.lang.reflect.MalformedParametersException: Invalid parameter name ""

Comment: The question does not contain enough details for us to understand the exact problem. Please consider editing it to add more details

Comment: We need some code and the full stack trace to be able to help you.

Comment: I'm 99% certain your problem is an Intellij problem, unrelated to Spring Boot. Try in your IDE: File > invalidate caches and restart. If that doesn't fix your problem, post a screen shot of the runconfiguration you're using. You'll probably want to edit your post and remove the spring-boot tag.

Comment: Sorry I cant share anything, Its related to my work. But I don't know this was fixed when i removed the debug point and ran it and placed debug point at the same place. I had done "invalid cash ans restart". Mostly related to Intellij I guess.

Comment: Same thing is happening with me , Its STS I am working with. I can hit my endpoint by normally running the application and it works fine, but when I put my application in debug mode, it starts thorwing me invalid parameter name exception and every time some new variable name it shows.

Comment: I ran into this after compiling a legacy app with Java 21 from the command line and then running it with Java 8 from IntelliJ.  Recompiling it with Java 8 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Same thing happening with me too with STS. Suddenly it started to give me error for invalid parameter name with debug mode. After loss of 3 hours , I removed all breakpoints from run menu-> Remove all Breakpoints and restarted the service again in debug mode. It worked. No STS or system restart required for me.
I think the issue was with debugger.

Comment: Yes removing all the breakpoints showing the exact error in both IntelliJ and STS else it is showing Invalid Parameter name ""

Answer (score 2):

No sure if this was the issue. But all I did was in Intellij I "invalidate caches and restart", closed intellij , restarted my PC, removed all the debug points and ran the code and placed the debug point again. it was fixed. weird!!

Answer (score 0):

Try `@PathVariable("<paramName>")` if your API end points do accept the path variables or parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I could "solve" this problem by starting the debugger first and then setting the break points including conditionals. I'm using STS as well. Removing the break points and adding again before the service starts did not work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).